# Unable to integrate vue-recaptcha 2.0.3 version in my vue project(version 2.7)

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to integrate vue-recaptcha(2.0.3) library in my existing vuejs project having version 2.7.0.
Here is the component having code

```
<template>
  <VueRecaptcha sitekey="keyname"></VueRecaptcha>
</template>

<script>
  import { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha';
  export default {
    components: { VueRecaptcha }
  };
</script>
```

When i ran, it give me this error

```
Unknown custom element: <VueRecaptcha> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I also tried by passing name as below but still getting error

```
<script>
  import { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha';
  export default {
    name: 'VueRecaptcha'
    components: { VueRecaptcha }
  };
</script>
```